# In .dotnet (c#) is an event still raised if nothing is subscribed to it?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, clr

It's a basic question, but I realized I don't know the answer.

In dotnet is an event still raised if nothing is subscribed to it?
Does the event know if it has subscribers?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it knows, event is basically a delegate with syntactic sugar, every delegate is an inheritor of MulticastDelegate, which has subscribers list inside. Technically it’s like a linked list, where one subscriber has a link to next one (delegate is immutable). Take a peek into MulticastDelegate dotnet core source code.